# How to compare two elements of different sheets

Tags: c#, mysql, list, datagridview

I need to display movie titles in dataGridView, but so that duplicate titles are not displayed. For this, I created two sheets. In the first I put the entire list of names, and in the second those that have already been displayed.

```
            table = new DataTable();
            string sql = "SELECT history FROM users WHERE login= '" + nameuser + "';";
            DB.usradapt(sql, 2);
            string[] histor = table.Rows[0]["history"].ToString().Split('/');

            List<string> pruv = new List<string>();
            List<string> pruv2 = new List<string>();
            pruv2.Add("0");

            table = new DataTable();
            foreach (var word in histor)
            {
                int counts = 0;
                sql = "SELECT NameFilm FROM films WHERE tags LIKE'" + $"%{word}%'";
                DB.usradapt(sql, 3);

                pruv.Add(tages.Rows[counts]["NameFilm"].ToString());


                    for (int j = 0; j < pruv2.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (pruv[counts] != pruv2[j])
                        {
                            pruv2.Add(pruv[counts]);
                            DB.usradapt(sql, 2);

                        }
                    }

                counts++;

            }
            dgvResult.DataSource = table;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tages;
```

But in the end, everything is displayed as if the comparison always returns true.
In theory, there should be no duplicate names in the left column.[tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeKl4.png)

Comment: first of all: **use parameterised queries!** - or enjoy loads of bugs as well as leaked data.

Comment: U can use Distinct() linq method on list to get unique items in a collection. In case u need to get common elements in two collection then use JOIN linq method.